# Existence of the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sin(2^n x)$ uniform convergences in $\mathbb{R}$, denote $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sin(2^n x)$$
can $f'(x)$ exist in $\mathbb{R}$, especially at $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which happens to not be differentiable anywhere. Loosely speaking, we would expect the derivative to be the sum of the derivatives of each term, so
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(2^nx)$$
which obviously diverges at $0$, and can be shown to diverge everywhere else, since there will be infinitely many terms $\cos(2^nx)$ with absolute value greater than $1/3$ (since if $|\cos(x)|<1/3$, then $|\cos(2x)|>1/3$ - so more than half the terms are greater than $1/3$ - tighter bounds exist, of course). At $0$, at least, what this shows is that the partial sums leading to $f$ become increasingly steep in that area, so the fact that the above sum diverges, though not yet constituting a *proof* that the derivative does not exist, essentially says that there is no finite linear upper bound on $f$ near $0$, meaning it is not differentiable (since the derivative stipulates linear bounds on $f$ that are valid locally)

Comment: Why do we expect the derivative is in that form? Given the series doesn't converge at $x=0$?

Comment: Well, in general, because of handwaving (since the derivative isn't actually continuous under the supremum norm, as is implicitly assumed here). In this particular case, each term is positive, which tells us that the partial sums leading to $f$, which are all lower bounds for $f$, in $[0,\varepsilon)$, have their least steep upper bound with arbitrarily large slope - meaning that any line through the origin must be below some partial sum near $0$, and hence below $f$, meaning there is no linear upper bound to $f$ through $0$ - so that this series diverges is meaningful.